# Shiny Server App Authentication by a Cookie Value

Tags: r, authentication, cookies, shiny, shinyjs

I created a directory of Shiny Apps on my Shiny Server that I want to have authenticated by a cookie value placed when the users are logged in to a website. All I need is shiny code that will read in a browser's cookie for a cookie named "placed_cookie" and if that value is equal to 5, let the user view the Shiny app. If the cookie does not = 5, then redirect to the login URL.

Currently this code below disconnects the user from the server when immediately opening on the server. No redirection is happening if there is no cookie or allowance to view the app if the cookie is present.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- '
  shinyjs.getcookie = function(params) {
      var cookie = Cookies.get("placed_cookie");
      Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", cookie);
  }'

jsmessage <- "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('mymessage', function(message) {window.location = 'http://www.google.com';});"

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "www/js.cookie.js"),
    tags$script(jsmessage)
  ),
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("pageCol")),

  titlePanel("Test Cookie App")

)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    js$getcookie()
    if(input$jscookie != 5){
      session$sendCustomMessage("mymessage", "mymessage")
    }

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help on this would be fantastic. I also have zero JS experience but I am learning slowly.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik currently this code disconnects the user from the server when immediately opening on the server. No redirection is happening if there is no cookie or allowance to view the app is the cookie is present.

Comment: Does it work locally? Try looking at the console in developer's tools in your favorite browser.